# Thymeleaf form for class like this:

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have class Customer

```
    public class Customer {

        private long id;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String pesel;
        private Address address;

        public Customer() {}

        public Customer(String firstName, String lastName, String pesel, Address address) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.address = address;
            this.pesel = pesel;
        }
}
```

and class Address

```
public class Address {

    private String country;
    private String city;
    private String street;
    private String streetNumber;
    private String zipCode;
}
```

How can I input from thymeleaf form? I mean for primitie type this is enought but how can I read address class?

```
    <form th:action="@{/addCustomer}" method="post" class="col m8 s12 offset-m2">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6">
                <input id="firstName" type="text"/>
                <label for="firstName">Imię</label>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field col s6">
                <input id="lastName" type="text"/>
                <label for="firstName">Nazwisko</label>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                    <input id="pesel" type="text">
                    <label for="pesel">Pesel</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Of course every relation between classes are, basically classes code is for example what fields I have

Comment: Are you trying to populate the Thymeleaf page from populated class instances?  Or are you trying to read the form data in your controller's "request mapping" method in order to populate class instances?

Comment: Hm I think it's a second option

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to declare the form's elements as input parameters to the request mapped method.  Something like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = '/trainInfo/trainDetails', method = RequestMethod.POST, produces='text/html')
public ModelAndView getTrainDetails(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
@RequestParam(name='username') String username) {
```

where `'username'` is the name of the HTML input element you want to access inside the method.